# Is possible to avoid version number in google endpoints URL

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have done a deployment on google app engine, with the app engine version as 1 in pom.xml it is generating url https://1-dot-xyx-app.appspot.com/_ah/api/ for the google end points.

Is there any possibility to have the url https://xyz-app.appspot.com/_ah/api/ for the google endpoints ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

https://xyz-app.appspot.com/_ah/api/ should directly work for your default version of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Rahul's answer is correct, but if version 1 isn't the default version of the application, then the answer is no - you will need to use https://1-dot-xyx-app.appspot.com/_ah/api/

This is because with more than one active version operating at a time, you can't have them both at the same location!